# undefined method with googlebooks

Tags: ruby, postgresql, google-books, sinatra-activerecord

I'm building a library in sinatra, using postresql as database and a 'googlebooks' gem to find the informations I want.

This is my code in main.rb

```
get '/list' do
  @books = GoogleBooks.search(params[:title])
  erb :list
end

get '/info/:isbn' do
  #this is to get the info from my database if there is any

   if book = Book.find_by(isbn: params[:isbn])
     @book_title = book.title
     @book_authors = book.author
     @book_year = book.year
     @book_page_count = book.page_count
     @book_id = book.id
     @book_isbn = book.isbn
  else
     #use the gem to look for the data

    text = GoogleBooks.search(params[:isbn])
    @book_title = text.title
    @book_author = text.authors
    @book_year = text.published_date
    @book_cover = text.image_link(:zoom => 2)
    @book_page_count = text.page_count
    @book_notes = text.description
   #and then store it into the database

   book = Book.new
   book.title = @book_title
   book.authors = @book_authors
   book.publish_date = @book_year
   book.image_link = @book_cover
   book.page_count = @book_page_count
   book.description = @book_notes
   book.isbn = params[:isbn]
   book.save
   @book_id = book.id

  end

 erb :info
end
```

This is my erb file :list

```
 <div class='list_by_title'>
   <% @books.each do |text| %>
     <ul>
       <li class='list_by_title'>
         <a href="/info/<%= text.isbn_10 %>"><%= text.title %>  (Authour: <%= text.authors %>)</a>
       </li>

     </ul>
    <%end%>
 </div>
```

The list part works.. I'm able to have a page with a list of titles... the problem is when I try to call the data from the params isbn, I always have this error:

```
  NoMethodError at /info/0596554877
 undefined method `title' for #<GoogleBooks::Response:0x007ff07a430e28>
```

Any idea for a possible solution?

Comment: You can log the JSON you are receiving from the API and check whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/googlebooks/0.0.8/GoogleBooks/Response), `GoogleBooks::Response` is an enumerator. So you need to iterate over it by using `each`, and invoke the `title` method on individual objects retrieved from enumerator.

---

```
result = GoogleBooks.search(params[:isbn])
result.each do |text|
  @book_title = text.title
  ...
end
```

---

Variable name `text` for details about a book is not a good name, you need to pick apt variable names, many  a times good variable names makes debugging easier